# Django + SQLite + ForeignKey('self') = Failed Migration

Tags: python, django, sqlite, migration

In Django 1.9 using SQLite as the database backend, I am getting an error when trying to apply migrations after modifying a model to use multi-table inheritance instead of the `OneToOneField` relationship it was previously using.

Particularly, the problem seems to be due to including a `ForeignKey('self')` in the model.

## models.py

Here is the app from which an initial migration is successfully made and applied:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Customer(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

## models.py (modified)

The app is then modified to inherit from the User model rather than linking to it:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(User):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

At this point a `./manage.py makemigrations <app>` succeeds but then applying the migration fails with:

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 221, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 181, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(temp_model)
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 250, in create_model
    to_column = field.remote_field.model._meta.get_field(field.remote_field.field_name).column
  File "/home/piranha/.virtualenvs/Python_3.5-Django_1.9/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 582, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist('%s has no field named %r' % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Customer has no field named 'id'
```

Again, the problem seems to only occur when using SQLite and including the self-referencing `ForeignKey`.  I think it is occurring because SQLite can't ALTER columns resulting in Django rebuilding the table, but the self-referencing `ForeignKey` is causing the rebuild to look for the 'id' column which no longer exists in the new model.

I've tried manually adjusting the migration operations every which way and even adding a `migrations.RunPython` with `apps.get_model()` to use the historical version of the model.  Nothing seems to work.

How can I adjust the following migration to avoid the error:

## Migration

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.9.2 on 2016-09-07 01:16
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('base', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='customer',
            options={'verbose_name': 'user', 'verbose_name_plural': 'users'},
        ),
        migrations.AlterModelManagers(
            name='customer',
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customer',
            name='account',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='customer',
            name='id',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='customer',
            name='user_ptr',
            field=models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, default=None, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

And, yes, I know I'll ultimately need to break the migration into multiple phases and do a data migration to put something useful in the new `user_ptr` field.

Comment: Do you have any preexisting migrations? If so, I'd suggest deleting all your migrations and starting them again

Comment: I reproduced this error using only the code above.  The only two migrations are the initial one (made from the first code block) and the second one which gives the error.

Comment: Right, I'd recommend deleting both files and restarting your migrations, see if that fixes the issue

Comment: That would just work-around the issue.  The actual code is deployed in a production environment with past migrations and restarting from scratch isn't a simple possibility.  And, regardless, I think there is a real issue here that needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it took me a while to work out: but basically, I don't think you can do this:

```
class Customer(User):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)
```

Instead, it should be something more like (untested:)

```
class Customer(User):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('admin.User', null=True)
```

If you want to make sure that data integrity is actually a Customer, you could put a pre-validate in save (or something, if you're using a save-pipeline of some kind)

If you include a data migration step to preserve that value as well, perhaps through using a temporary value to store it in (or dump and reinsert the objects).